# Slow DOM Change with v-show

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I've been troubleshooting an issue where, inside of a nested `v-for` loop, a simple `v-show` directive is taking up toward *4 seconds* to actually apply the `display: none;` attribute in the DOM.

The basic layout is this. I've changed the actual naming to be all about cars; because why not!

*I do apologize for the wall of code, but I felt it was relevant to include a basic jist of the component structure.*

```html
    <div class="vehicle-history" v-if="fetchComplete && !fetchError">
            <h3 class="header-bold">History</h3>
            <div class="history-container" v-for="car in vehicles.cars" :key="car.id">
                    <div class="vehicle-header">
                            <div class="toyota" v-if="car.model == 'toyota'">
                                    <span class="model-id">@{{ car.type }}_@{{ car.id }}</span> - @{{ car.title }}
                            </div>
                            <div class="audi" v-if="car.model == 'audi'">
                                    <span class="model-id">@{{ car.type }}_@{{ car.id }}</span> - @{{ car.title }}
                            </div>
                            <div class="benz" v-if="car.model == 'benz'">
                                    <span class="model-id">@{{ car.type }}_@{{ car.id }}</span> - @{{ car.title }}
                            </div>
                            <div class="rolls" v-if="car.model == 'rolls'">
                                    <span class="model-id">@{{ car.type }}_@{{ car.id }}</span> - @{{ car.title }}
                            </div><br />
                            <small v-for="color in car.colors">@{{ color.name }}&nbsp;</small>
                    </div>

                    <div class="vehicle-body">
                            <div class="description">@{{ car.description }}</div>

                            <div class="review-container" v-if="car.reviews.length > 5">
                                    <div class="review" v-for="n in (0, 4)" :key="car.reviews[n].id">
                                            <strong>@{{ car.reviews[n].rating }}</strong> - @{{ car.reviews[n].content }}<br />
                                            <small>@{{ car.reviews[n].created_at.date }} @{{ car.reviews[n].created_at.timezone }}</small>

                                            <span v-show="n == 4 && !car.displayFull"><br />
                                                    <button type="button"
                                                                    class="btn btn-link"
                                                                    data-toggle="collapse"
                                                                    v-on:click="car.displayFull = true"
                                                                    v-bind:data-target="'#expanded-reviews-' + car.id">More details
                                                    </button>
                                            </span>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="collapse" v-bind:id="'expanded-reviews-' + car.id">
                                            <div class="review" v-for="n in (4, car.reviews.length-1)" :key="car.reviews[n].id">
                                                    <strong>@{{ car.reviews[n].rating }}</strong> - @{{ car.reviews[n].content }}<br />
                                                    <small>@{{ car.reviews[n].created_at.date }} @{{ car.reviews[n].created_at.timezone }}</small>

                                                    <span v-if="n == car.reviews.length-1"><br />
                                                            <button type="button"
                                                                            class="btn btn-link"
                                                                            data-toggle="collapse"
                                                                            v-on:click="car.displayFull = false"
                                                                            v-bind:data-target="'#expanded-reviews-' + car.id">Less details
                                                            </button>
                                                    </span>
                                            </div>
                                    </div>
                            </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
    </div>
```

**What I've tried**

- Adding the `:key` to the relevant loops
- Moving the `v-show` attribute from the button (where it was originally at) to the parent span.
- Wrapping it in `<keep-alive>` (which didn't work at all, it broke visibility as a whole)
- Swapping `v-show` for `v-if` and vice-versa

**The expected output**

What I'm trying to accomplish is to make sure the button for "More details" hides away when the accordion gets expanded (that is, when the "More details" button is initially clicked) and re-appears if the "Less details" button is clicked.

**The actual output**

Whilst it does the above, there's a delay of between 2-5 seconds from clicking the button, to it getting the `display: none;` attribute applied in the DOM. The change to the Vue variable however appears instant.

Do you have any clue why this may be, and if there's a good workaround for this? Thank you, as always!

**UPDATE**

Revised code example below based on a number of suggestions. This is a flat out copy of existing code, so no changes to naming this time around.

```html
<div class="incident-history text-center col-xs-12 padding-bottom" v-if="fetchComplete && !fetchError">
        <h3 class="heading3 black-text">Incident History</h3>
        <div class="incident-container" v-for="incident in responseData.incident.resolved" :key="incident.id">
                <div class="incident-header">
                        <div :class="'title-' + incident.classification">
                                <span class="incident-id">@{{ incident.type }}_@{{ incident.id }}</span> - @{{ incident.title }}
                        </div><br />
                        <small v-for="monitor in incident.monitors">@{{ monitor.name }}&nbsp;</small>
                </div>

                <div class="incident-body">
                        <div class="description">@{{ incident.content }}</div>
                        <div class="update" v-for="(comment, index) in incident.comments.slice(0,5)">
                                <strong>@{{ comment.type }}</strong> - @{{ comment.content }}<br />
                                <small>@{{ comment.created_at.date }} @{{ comment.created_at.timezone }}</small>
                        </div>

                        <div class="collapse"
                                 v-bind:id="'expanded-update-' + incident.id"
                                 v-if="incident.comments.length > 4">

                                <div class="update" v-for="(comment, index) in incident.comments.slice(5)">
                                        <strong>@{{ comment.type }}</strong> - @{{ comment.content }}<br />
                                        <small>@{{ comment.created_at.date }} @{{ comment.created_at.timezone }}</small>
                                </div>
                        </div>

                        <button type="button"
                                        class="btn btn-link"
                                        data-toggle="collapse"
                                        v-show="incident.comments.length > 4 && !incident.displayFull"
                                        v-on:click="incident.displayFull = !incident.displayFull"
                                        v-bind:data-target="'#expanded-update-' + incident.id">Show more
                        </button>

                        <button type="button"
                                        class="btn btn-link"
                                        data-toggle="collapse"
                                        v-show="incident.comments.length > 4 && incident.displayFull"
                                        v-on:click="incident.displayFull = !incident.displayFull"
                                        v-bind:data-target="'#expanded-update-' + incident.id">Show less
                        </button>
                </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

I will note that the above code block is run inside of yet another for-loop. The basic topology is this (lengths may vary)

```html
responseData: Object
    incident: Object
        active: Array[4]
            0: Object
            1: Object
                Property: SomeValue
                Property: SomeValue
                Property: SomeValue
                Property: SomeValue
                Property: SomeValue
                Comments: Array[3]
                    0: Object
                    1: Object
                        Property: SomeValue
                        Property: SomeValue
                    2: Object
            2: Object
            3: Object
```

**Alternative Solution**

I've come up with a working, and likely better alternative for the changing of "Read more" to "Read less" and vice versa.

```css
button.full-details[aria-expanded="true"]:after {
        content: 'Show less';
}
button.full-details[aria-expanded="false"]:after {
        content: 'Show more';
}
```

This works fine, and just needs adding a few lines of CSS as well as a class to the button (or targeting the Bootstrap button class, but that's not great for many reasons).

That said, I'm going to leave this one open for a little bit to hopefully gain an understanding into why the issue arose with Vue in the first place.

Comment: What exactly do you intend to do with `n in (0,4)`? I'm unfamiliar with that syntax.

Comment: @LuisOrduz In that case it'd be equivalent to ```n in 4```, I just use it for semantic reasons since I use ```n in (4,length)``` somewhere else, which starts iterating from 4.

Comment: No, it won't (or it shouldn't), the comma operator just returns the last operand, using `n in (4, length)` is just `n in length`. Look at this [pen](https://codepen.io/luord/pen/VraPye).

Comment: @LuisOrduz Interesting! Admittedly I just found a comment suggesting it on a GitHub issue and never verified much as I was working on the issue described in this topic. Appreciate the input - I'll have to rewrite that part.

Comment: Are you changing display after async operation? After any ajax call?

Comment: @CmdrSharp Of course it is take a while, when you are changing display to none in callback of any ajax call.

Comment: @WaldemarIce I think you're misunderstanding. There's no requests happening when changing display to none. It's updating the virtual DOM, and the actual DOM is just seeing a delay. It doesn't re-fetch the data when the button is clicked. Or am I misunderstanding what you're trying to say?

Answer (score 1):

It is surprising to hear 2-5 secs lag in display, but then there's quite a bit going on in that template. Hard to tell if suggested changes will impact the page visuals, without a test system.

The button(s) seems most problematic, creates one per review but only needs one per car, has to evaluate v-show or v-if for all of them.

Have one button outside the reviews loop,

```html
 <button class="btn btn-link" type="button" 
  data-toggle="collapse" :data-target="'#expanded-reviews-' + car.id"
  @click="car.displayFull = !car.displayFull">
    {{ buttonPrompt(car.displayFull) }}
 </button>
```

I'd also consider creating a **car** child component, even a **review** grandchild component, as reasoning about the layout becomes difficult when it's that busy.

The final thing is so obvious, I'm thinking it must be an artifact of the domain renaming.

This

```html
    <div class="toyota" v-if="car.model == 'toyota'">
      <span class="model-id">@{{ car.type }}_@{{ car.id }}</span> - @{{ car.title }}
    </div>
    <div class="audi" v-if="car.model == 'audi'">
      <span class="model-id">@{{ car.type }}_@{{ car.id }}</span> - @{{ car.title }}
    </div>
    <div class="benz" v-if="car.model == 'benz'">
      <span class="model-id">@{{ car.type }}_@{{ car.id }}</span> - @{{ car.title }}
    </div>
    <div class="rolls" v-if="car.model == 'rolls'">
      <span class="model-id">@{{ car.type }}_@{{ car.id }}</span> - @{{ car.title }}
    </div>
```

could become this

```html
    <div :class="car.model">
      <span class="model-id">{{ car.type }}_{{ car.id }}</span> - {{ car.title }}
    </div>
```

Also, what is this? `@{{`?

---

**Edit after comment - on the question of how many buttons are created**

It sounds like you are expecting only one or two buttons to be rendered? Here's a test.

From a spec for `Cars.vue` created with your template,

Test data has 6 reviews,

```js
<script>
  export default {
    data () {
      return {
        fetchComplete: true,
        fetchError: false,
        cars: [
          {
            model: 'toyota',
            type: 'hatch',
            id: 1,
            title: 'corolla',
            description: 'grey corolla',
            colors: [{name: 'grey'}, {name: 'grey'}, {name: 'grey'}],
            reviews: [
              {rating: 2, content: 'its grey', created_at: {date: ''}},
              {rating: 2, content: 'its grey', created_at: {date: ''}},
              {rating: 2, content: 'its grey', created_at: {date: ''}},
              {rating: 2, content: 'its grey', created_at: {date: ''}},
              {rating: 2, content: 'its grey', created_at: {date: ''}},
              {rating: 2, content: 'its grey', created_at: {date: ''}},
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    },
```

The test,

```js
it('count the buttons', () => {
  const buttons = wrapper.element.querySelectorAll('button');
  console.log(buttons)
})
```

Results,

```html
LOG LOG: Object{
  0: <button type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#expanded-reviews-1" class="btn btn-link">More details</button>, 
  1: <button type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#expanded-reviews-1" class="btn btn-link">More details</button>, 
  2: <button type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#expanded-reviews-1" class="btn btn-link">More details</button>, 
  3: <button type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#expanded-reviews-1" class="btn btn-link">More details</button>, 
  4: <button type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#expanded-reviews-1" class="btn btn-link">Less details</button>, 
length: 5}
```

Then, there's the question of whether the change detection cycle is smart enough ***not*** to re-evaluate button creation each cycle. I'll see if we can test that too.

---

**Placement of v-if**

It just occurred to me, this

```html
<button class="btn btn-link" ... >
  <span v-if="n === car.reviews.length-1">Less details</span>
</button>
```

***might*** be better as this

```html
<button class="btn btn-link" ... v-if="n === car.reviews.length-1">
  Less details
</button>
```

---

**Missing first review**

The `v-for="n in (0, 4)"` loop seems to miss out the first review. If I set the ratings to be sequential numbers, the first is not displayed.

```html
<div class="review" v-for="n in (0, 4)">
  <strong>@{{ car.reviews[n].rating }}</strong> - @{{ car.reviews[n].content }}
```

Try

```html
<div class="review" v-for="(review,n) of car.reviews.slice(0,5)" :key="review.id">
  <strong>@{{ review.rating }}</strong> - @{{ review.content }}

...

<div class="review" v-for="(review,n) of car.reviews.slice(5)">
```

(keeping n for button v-if expression).

Comment: The buttons were actually changed (notice how v-show is v-if further down in the example code). It should thus only create that element if it evaluates to the last child. The example above does that now too, I merely experimented to see the difference in rendering.

I will look into re-structuring it to nest everything a bit smarter however. I'll update the question if I find a working solution, but even so, my example above seems pretty basic and shouldn't result in that long of a render time.

```@{{``` is just blade syntax - the example was used in a Laravel project.

Comment: Much appreciate your many suggestions here!
I've made quite a few revisions and will update my answer. Unfortunately, the problem itself remains. There's several seconds worth of delay before "Show more" becomes "Show less" in the example.

Comment: I look forward to seeing the revisions.

Comment: They're up! Again, much appreciate your input - you'll hopefully see I've taken to incorporating most of these now - vastly reducing the amount of properties on the DOM.

Comment: I went ahead and added some information about how the data I work with looks in Vue here as well. Not sure if that helps, but I figure it may explain the level of scoping I've tried to do.

Comment: Also added the alternative solution I went with, which wound up being a CSS version of what I was trying to achieve. That said, the basic question at hand remains so I'll leave this open in the hopes of gaining understanding of what causes this in the first place.

Comment: Well done, good solution. The shape of the css indicates you have one button now, which maybe also indicates interaction between the two buttons (in terms of re-triggering change detection). Maybe `v-on:click` and `v-show` both changing **and** being dependent on `incident.displayFull`.

Comment: Good thinking! I'll try to verify if that was the case. Thanks again for your solid input!